# KeyError al intentar usar un JSON como diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Lo que quiero hacer con este script es primeramente que me muestre los valores por separado, pero el error que obtengo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la función que estoy usando:

```py
def editarproducto():
    limpiar()
    i5=input('Código del producto (0 para salir): ')
    if i5=='':
        print('Introduzca el código del producto.')
        time.sleep(1)
        limpiar()
        editarproducto()
    if i5=='0':
        time.sleep(1)
        limpiar()
        editarproducto()
    productos={}
    ep=open('datos/8462eb2cfb69f8c8ddc8e366dce0a815497b71c3f9f5a44263b4ccff865bc8a6b9e3a61ef1b15c37777a9b445f251d2abf0ab0f6fe988386f0266e45def3b536.json', 'r').read()
    productos['código']=ep
    valor=productos[i5]
    print(f'codigo:{valor["nombre"]}')
```

Este es el JSON que uso como diccionario:

```
{"código": "1", "nombre": "Fideos Rébora", "precio": "48", "stock": "150"}{"código": "2", "nombre": "Chocolate Nesquik", "precio": "69", "stock": "200"}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el cómo manejas los datos, si bien, estás cargando el archivo con la función `open()` que de hecho te recomiendo revisar la documentación de [Manejo de Archivos](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) donde efectivamente hacen referencia a dicha función para la carga de datos a partir de un archivo, mencionan que además de la buena práctica de utilizar la palabra reservada `with` para gestionar el manejo de lectura escritura.

La función `read()` devuelve un dato de tipo `string`, no un diccionario, por lo tanto al intentar acceder a tu "json" como un diccionario, realmente estás intentando acceder a un string.

Tu problema se soluciona del siguiente modo:

```py
import json

# Asumo tienes otros imports y funciones.

def editarproducto():
    limpiar()
    i5 = input('Código del producto (0 para salir): ')
    if i5 == '':
        print('Introduzca el código del producto.')
        time.sleep(1)
        limpiar()
        editarproducto()
    if i5 == '0':
        time.sleep(1)
        limpiar()
        editarproducto()
    productos={}
    with open('datos/8462eb2cfb69f8c8ddc8e366dce0a815497b71c3f9f5a44263b4ccff865bc8a6b9e3a61ef1b15c37777a9b445f251d2abf0ab0f6fe988386f0266e45def3b536.json', 'r') as ep:
        productos['código'] = json.load(ep)
    valor = productos[i5] # Seguramente esta linea tampoco funciona porque no almacenaste el json de EP en la etiqueta del código, sino en la etiqueta codigo literal.
    # Probablemente sea algo como
    # productos[i5] = json.load(ep)
    # y después accedas como
    # valor = productos[i5]
    print(f'codigo:{valor["nombre"]}')
```

Aún ahí, necesitas agregar validaciones para asegurarte de que el archivo siempre poseerá la estructura que necesitas, entre otras posibles correcciones o mejoras a tu código, de cualquier modo, eso resuelve tu problema inicial, te recomiendo leer también la documentación del módulo [Json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) de Python.

Comment: no se como va en python, pero aqui hay un problema bastante importante. El algoritmo usa recursividad en los casos de cadena vacia y cadena 0, con lo que no esta saliendo de la funcion... Esto puede generarte a la larga un problema de memoria. Aparte, el indice al que se accede de `productos` no esta comprobado, se podria introducir como codigo de producto 857, o incluso -1...

Comment: Efectivamente, tiene una serie de cosas por validar, su único problema no parece ser el de manejar un JSON aunque es lo que nos compete en esta pregunta, los problemas de recursividad, el no validar la existencia de valores y aparentemente no tener un Error Handling apropiado, el index de "codigo de producto" podría dar resultados inesperados si no revisa siquiera que se contenga ese número de elementos, supongo que tenemos que esperar a que defina si necesita más ayuda con eso.

Comment: Lo comento más que nada porque según mucha gente de por aquí, cuando alguien hace una pregunta sobre formularios, e casi obligatorio advertirle de problemas de SQL injection (aún cuando no se está preguntando por ello). En este caso va a tener problemas de memoria, por eso me ha parecido correcto advertirle

Comment: Entiendo, esa parte la desconocía, pero tiene sentido, gracias.